# Apache Camel : is there a way to reuse resources that aren't thread-safe in a threaded environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

I have a web service based on Camel that can be summarised like this in Java DSL :

```
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        MyResource myResource = new MyResource();
        
        from("jetty:...")
            .setHeader("myResource", constant(myResource))
            .bean(MyProcessor.class)
        ;
    }
}
```

The data stored in `myResource` is necessary for the processing in the bean `MyProcessor`.

The initialisation of `myResource` can be quite long (few seconds), so I want to prepare it ahead of time when the app is starting, rather than initialising a throwaway copy at runtime every time there is a request on the service (aiming for milliseconds response times).

The code above worked fine when I was the only user of the service, but after doing some automated load testing, it appeared that some parts of `myResource` that are beyond my reach (external libraries) are not thread-safe.

Since I can't fix the the "thread-unsafety" of `myResource`, I was hoping for a way to instantiate *N* distinct copies of `myResource`, so that each Camel-Jetty thread can use safely their own copy of `myResource`, but I didn't find any info on doing that in the documentation page about threads : https://camel.apache.org/manual/threading-model.html

Has anyone encountered and solved that issue before?

Comment: I suppose you could use a `ThreadLocal`...

Comment: “Since I can't fix the the "thread-unsafety" of myResource” — but you can. If nothing else, `synchronize` every method on your resource.

Comment: @BasilBourque : well, if that's the only answer, I might as well just configure my app so that Camel-Jetty is restrict to use only a single thread, that should be roughly the same performance but with less risks of interlocking.

Comment: @Jorn : Never heard of it until now, but it seems pretty useful. I'm however not sure of how to access the threads used by Apache Camel, so I don't know where I could place one of those ThreadLocal variables.

Comment: @Alef You don't have to manage that yourself, ThreadLocal will use the current thread automatically.